# h2o is not using all processors

Tags: h2o

I have a server with 48 processors.

The server is not virtualized and the h2o sees 48 processors, but 16 of them for some reason are not being used.

Any advice?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyDWU.png)

Comment: Which algorithm are you training and what version of H2O?

Comment: deeplearning  3.8.0.2

Comment: I tried running two models at once, h2o is still not using all of the processors .   I have a hunch its a java issue

Comment: R is connected to the H2O cluster: 
    H2O cluster uptime:         8 hours 28 minutes 
    H2O cluster version:        3.8.0.2 
    H2O cluster name:           root 
    H2O cluster total nodes:    1 
    H2O cluster total memory:   26.67 GB 
    H2O cluster total cores:    48 
    H2O cluster allowed cores:  32 
    H2O cluster healthy:        TRUE

Answer (score 3):

It looks like somehow your H2O cluster was launched with 32 cores instead of the full 48.  That's what "H2O cluster allowed cores: 32" indicates is happening.  To use all the cores, do the following:

1. Shut down your existing H2O cluster using `h2o.shutdown()`
2. Start a new H2O cluster from R using `h2o.init(nthreads = -1)`, which means that it will use all available cores.  If for some reason that does not work, try `h2o.init(nthreads = 48)`.
3. You can also start the H2O cluster from the command line by typing the following:  `java -Xmx30g -jar h2o.jar -nthreads 48` and then use `h2o.init()` to connect inside R.

Feel free to also upgrade to the [latest stable version of H2O](http://www.h2o.ai/download/h2o/r) (3.8.0.2 is slightly outdated, now we are at 3.8.1.1).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this was a limitation in the old version. Using 3.10 and testing 3.12 now issue was fixed.